# Compilation Failure when Making a Production Build with create-react-app v2

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, create-react-app

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

Lexical error on line 1: Unrecognized text.
  Erroneous area:
1: $progress-size - 2 * $border-size
^..^
```

I encounter the above compilation failure when doing a **production build** after **migrating from create-react-app v1 to create-react-app v2**. The local development, i.e: `yarn start`, is working properly.

**NOTE:** I do not encounter this issue in create-react-app v1.

I tried fixing this by using `SCSS` interpolation, i.e: wrap `$progress-size` and `$border-size` with `#{}` --> `#{$progress-size}` `#{$border-size}` and it solves the problems.

[Screenshot of the above error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgoNX.png)

Can anyone explain why I have to fix it like that and if there's a better way?